# Появилась ошибка - Uncaught Error: The key "" isn't declared

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

работало нормально и вдруг перестало показывать всплывающие формы.
В консоли выдает ошибку
Uncaught Error: The key "" isn't declared

[image: Скрин ошибки в консоли браузера]

Ругается на 111 строку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в 111 строке все как обычно, никто ничего не менял, и ошибки этой раньше не было.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: у вас searchcontrolProvider некорректно указан пустой строкой из-за этого и падает

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблемма была именно в этом. Но все равно странно, что ругается библиотека на ключ, имхо это не правильно.

Comment: В данном случае "ключ" это переменная, т.е. ошибка означает, что никакого ключевого слова " " не объявлено.